# How do i display the built-in gallery inside a widget?

Tags: widgets, shortcode, gallery

I want to display a specific gallery (without a plugin = WordPress built-in gallery) inside a widget. I tried the shortcode `[gallery ids="717"]` but that doesn't work. Maybe a workaround could be enabling shortcodes inside widgets? if yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widgets don't usually allow shortcodes in them (they treat them as normal text).

What you have to do, is to tell this widget, it should run `do_shortcode` on it's text. To do it, you can use this snippet:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Just place it in your `function.php` file. Then you can place shortcodes in Text Widget and they will work normally.